# HTTP 400 Bad Request - Invalid Header with Retrofit on Android

Tags: android, asp.net, apache-httpclient-4.x, bad-request, retrofit

I'm migrating my Android project from [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/index.html) to [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) with [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/). POST/PUT request return error, even though the application custom headers are the same and Content-Length of both request are equal.

- GET: work fine.
- POST/PUT: `Http Error 400 Bad Request - Invalid Header`. even though

For reference, the server is implemented using `ASP.NET` on `Windows Azure`.

**Apache HttpClient**:

```
HttpPut put = new HttpPut(<URL>);
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
se.setContentType("application/json");
put.setEntity(se);
response = client.execute(put);
```

**Retrofit** + **OkHttp**:

```
// API
@PUT("/<path>")
Response updateThing(@Body Dto dto);

// OkHttpClient
@Override
public Response execute(Request r) throws IOException {
    List<Header> headers = HttpHelper.headerFor(method, url, etc);

    // Create new request with required headers
    Request encodedRequest = new Request(method, url, headers, r.getBody());
    return super.execute(encodedRequest);
}
```

The server returns:

```
---> HTTP PUT https://example.com/path
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 53
{"user_id":"0","latitude":"0.0","longitude":"0.0"}
---> END HTTP (53-byte body)
PUT https://example.com/path
Authorization Basic bmfweEskWkvlabF0ZSQ=
Content-Type application/json
Accept application/json
HashKey 8eb93b898ddc2b74685ed2be64c76cc3af973ebc6b628781fe50eedcbe29376f
<--- HTTP 400 https://example.com/path (1397ms)
: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
Content-Length: 339
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Date: Sat, 04 Jan 2014 08:26:45 GMT
OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1388824004870
OkHttp-Response-Source: NETWORK 400
OkHttp-Selected-Transport: http/1.1
OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1388824004785
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

<--- END HTTP (339-byte body)
```

**Edit**:

- Sending POST/PUT requests using online [Hurl.it](http://www.hurl.it/) works.
- Sending POST/PUT requests without any body using Retrofit works too.

Comment: Is it your post or some of headers don't have ':' devider

Comment: @EugenMartynov thanks! It's the Content-Type header which got duplicated.

Comment: Great! Sometimes such minor mistakes stop us for several hours

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the server expects as a header parameter, but you can pass any header value on the client interface

```
@PUT("/<path>")
Response updateThing(@Header("headerName") String headerName, @Body Dto dto);
```

Comment: Hash stuff is created based on the http method, url, and parameters itself, so I use request interception method instead of `@Header` annotation.